# Access denied for remote cloudSQL from a cloud instance

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have two VM instances in google cloud console connecting to the same cloud SQL database, with no issues. I created a new instance and I can't connect it to the cloud SQL. The new instance was created as follows:

- Clone an existing instance that works with the database.
- Add the new ephemeral IP to the list of authorized networks of the database.
- SSH to the new instance and connect to mysql with the same command that works on the other two instances.

Mysql connection is denied for the user:

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p -h <cloudSQL IP>
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'IP' (using password: YES)
```

Am I missing something? I have followed the documentation and I can't find any similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

After one or two hours it was working. Changes took a while though. I tried restarting both the instances and the database, unsuccessfully. But time did the trick.